# Ternary operator not parsing

Tags: angular

Any help or hint would be grealy appreciated.
In the "dropmenu" tag, for title the value is "Open/Close Document Menu" if the getHeader returns "Documents" but should be "Open/Close Supporting Document menu" if getHeader returns "Supporting Documents".

```typescript
getHeader() {
  return this.docGroup == 'PACKAGED' ? "Documents" : "Supporting Documents";   
}
```

```html
<gadget 
  [expanded]="true"
  titleStr="{{titleStr}}" 
  [lockable]=lockable 
  [allDownloadable]="docList.length>1" 
  [locked]=locked 
  (lockClicked)="onLockClicked()" 
  [addable]="addable" 
  [header]="getHeader()" 
  (add)="showAddDoc()" 
  (downlloadAll)=downloadAll()
>
  <div class="gadget-body"  style="margin-top: 2px; padding: 5px;">
  <!-- Main Loop -->
    <div *ngFor="let node of docList;let i = index">
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; line-height:16px; margin-bottom:2px; margin-right: 5px;">
        <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; width:calc(100% - 120px);">
          <dropmenu 
            title="Open/Close Document Menu"
            [items]="getContextMenuItems(node)"
            (onSelect)="onClick($event)"
            [dropdownStyles]="{'left': 'calc(100% - 120px)'}"
            docRowId="{{node.id}}" [addTabIndex]="node.active" 
          ></dropmenu>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried this way:

```html
<dropmenu
  title= "return getHeader() == 'Documents' ? 'Open/Close Document Menu' : 'Open/Close Supporting Document Menu'"
  [items]="getContextMenuItems(node)"
  (onSelect)="onClick($event)"
  [dropdownStyles]="{'left': 'calc(100% - 120px)'}"
  docRowId="{{node.id}}"
  [addTabIndex]="node.active"
>
```

It doesn't work. It display the code:
I want the title="Open/Close Document Menu" or "Open/close Supporting Document".
Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Have you tried string interpolation i.e. `title="{{getHeader() == 'Documents' ? 'Open/Close Document Menu' : 'Open/Close Supporting Document Menu'}}"`?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!! For your help!!

Comment: You can use "interpolation -the `{{` `}}` or binding -`[` `]`. binding is:`[title]= "getHeader() == 'Documents' ? 'Open/Close Document Menu' : 'Open/Close Supporting Document Menu'"`

Answer (score 0):

Although your question was answered in the comment, it's not the ideal answer, and there's much to improve. And the first thing to start with is getting rid of function calls in the template. There are multiple articles about it, why is it really bad practice, [for example.](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-dont-call-a-function-inside-the-template-anymore-e74ebf499bb8)

If you want to see what it does, add a `console.log` to your `getHeader` function and then check the dev tools in browser.

```typecsript
getHeader() {
  console.log(this.docGroup == 'PACKAGED');
  return this.docGroup == 'PACKAGED' ? "Documents" : "Supporting Documents";   
}
```

You should see the console being swarmed with `true/false` for as long as the component is alive.

The way you can change it is to move the `getHeader` function call to a place in a .ts code, where you obtain the value of `this.docGroup`. Then you'll get rid of the function call in the template and make your code a bit more effective.

```typescript
// can be called in subscribe, if you obtain the data from some service call
// or in ngOnInt if passed as an input to the component

setHeader(): void {
  // add new public component properties gadgetHeader and dropDownTitle
  this.gadgetHeader = this.docGroup == 'PACKAGED' ? "Documents" : "Supporting Documents";   
  this.dropDownTitle = this.docGroup == 'PACKAGED' ? "Open/Close Document menu" : "Open/Close Supporting Document menu";
}
```

Then in HTML, just set them:

```header
<gadget 
  ...
  [header]="gadgetHeader" 
>
<dropmenu
  ...
  [title]="dropDownTitle" 
>
```

This way, you'll set the `header` and `title` only when there was some change in the `docGroup` and you'll get rid of the never-ending loop you introduced.